# How do I load a yolov5l model with custom weights into torch in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I have trained a yolov5l model for object detection and classification. I want to use the exported weights to identify images in a program I am creating. I am having trouble finding much of anything on how to use .pt weights in a python program.

I believe I use the "torch.load" method from the pytorch library, but when I try: `torch.load(path_to_weights)`
I get a ModuleNotFoundError for not having a module named 'models'.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `torch.load_state_dict()` method to load your trained parameters to your model in addition to `torch.load()`.

There are some issues with your `torch.load()` method. You should provide your path parameter as a either string or os.PathLike object. (These are written in the docs).

I am going to provide a simple code block to show you the way.

```
#Initializing model

model = Model() # Assuming your model's name is Model

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path_to_weights))
```

But don't forget that your path_to_weights parameter must be either string or os.PathLike object.